# Running untrusted code using chroot

Tags: virtual-machine, sandbox, chroot

I wish to run some untrusted code using `chroot`.

However, many claim that `chroot` is not a security feature and can easily be broken out of.

Therefore my question is how does apps like https://ideone.com/ manage to run untrusted code quickly and securely. Also if `chroot` can be broken out of, couldn't it be possible to break out of `chroot` in https://ideone.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what untrusted code you're referring to, but chroot just changes the apparent file structure -- theoretically you can't see above a certain level.  But symbolic links can still work so if your chrooted directory has a symlink to a directory above, chroot doesn't do you any good.

It's also possible for applications can get access to resources through other applications.  Some clever hackers know how to exploit running apps, but if you set up the ideone environment as root, well, anything is possible.

More theoretically, you could install a master application that has full access to the file system.  Then you run code in a chrooted environment. If that master app is running and listening it can relay resources to your chrooted application.

Quickly? Sure... Securely... well... with my example the master app is a gatekeeper but it's still security through trust of the master app.

Comment: So how does ideone execute user code (potentially malicious)?

Comment: "Ideone is an online compiler and debugging tool which allows you to compile source code and execute it online in more than 60 programming languages." -- flexible tools lead to flexible solutions.  Again, chroot is just a file system security configuration, if your code calls some running process that can access outside your chrooted filesystem then all bets are off.